# Angular - Choose from list and set to button

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have this directive :

```
app.directive('sampleDirective' , function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.numbers = [
                    {number : '1 '},
                    {number : '2 '},
                    {number : '3'},
                    {number : '4'},
                ];
        }
    }
});
```

I call this number in list like this:

```
          <sample-directive>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle">choose number<i class="icon icon-arrow-down"></i></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled text-right">
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in numbers">
                  <a href = "#"> {{ x.number }} </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
          </sample-directive>
```

At this moment , list can show numbers but I want to change *choose number* to selected value..(for example if I choose *1* I want to set it as value of button) How to do that?

Comment: "set it's value to button": what does that mean? Why do you use a directive to initialize an array in the scope? Just put that code in the controller. You shouldn't be using a directive to do that.

Comment: @JBNizet why? why I shouldn't use it?

Comment: Because that's not what directives are meant for. The model of a page should be handled by its controller, not by directives. There is no reason to add elements in the DOM that don't represent anything, and are just used to add an array to the scope. Moreover, the markup suggests that the array exists only between <sample-directive> and </sample-directive>, which is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$scope.setSelectedNumber = function(n) {
    $scope.selectedNumber = n;
}
```

In your link:

```
<a href="" ng-click="setSelectedNumber(x.number)"> {{ x.number }} </a>
```

In your button:

```
{{ selectedNumber ? selectedNumber : 'choose number' }}
```

or even simpler:

```
{{ selectedNumber || 'choose number' }}
```

Comment: It wasn't change button's value

Comment: You still haven't clarified. Which button are you talking about. Where have you put `{{ selectedNumber }}`?

Comment: <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle"  >{{loading ? '{{ selectedNumber }}' : 'choose number'}}<i class="icon icon-arrow-down"></i></button>

Comment: I want to change choose number to selected value.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can work

```
 <a href = "#" ng-click="setNumber(x.number)"> {{ x.number }} </a>

 $scope.setNumber = function(num){
 $scope.btnValue = num

 }

<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle">choose number<i class="icon icon-arrow-down" ng-value="btnValue"></i></button>
```